# How to get to Bluetooth settings that are not in the metro form?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, modern-ui

I have Windows 10 and when I pair a device for the first time using this form...

[image: Metro Bluetooth Form]

...it launches `C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\BTWUIExt.exe` which has some additional features that I can't find anywhere else, and looks like this:

[image: Bluetooth Form]

**Question:** How do I get to the setup form that looks like the one above? I can't figure out for the life of me how to get back to it after the device is paired.

**Note:** If I open the bluetooth device properties and go to the `Bluetooth Device Address` as pictured below...

[image: Bluetooth Properties]

...I can run this command `C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\BTWUIExt.exe /deviceAddr=E4F04237414B` and get it to launch. This doesn't seem practical at all though. There has to be a better way??

Comment: The software from that link is under a slightly different path `\ThinkPad\` vs `\WIDCOMM\`. It makes me think it's just shitty driver software that's designed to be called with a device address. I bet it worked with older versions of windows, but newer versions don't "do" that method anymore except during initial pairing. So it may just be a crap software implementation, where they don't realize that it's hiding a bunch of advanced properties.